# probability of normally distributed variable being greater then another normally distributed variable

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution

i have seen this question being addressed around, but I have problem with deriving the proof. Namely, if we have two normally distributed variables, $x$ and $y$, with their distributions given as $p_x(x)$ and $p_y(y)$, then for arbitrary $n$, the probability of x being less than n and y being greater than n we have:

$P(x\leq n \wedge y>n) = \int_{-\infty}^n f_x(x)dx \int_n^\infty f_y(y)dy$

If this is correct, which I think is, then for all possible numbers, the probability $P(x<y)$ should be:

$P(x<y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^n f_x(x)dx \int_n^\infty f_y(y)dy dn $

Well, now I have problem to get the same result as it was pointed out for example here: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/07/26/random-inequalities-ii-analytical-results/

I hope somebody can explain me where am I wrong.

Best

Answer (score 0):

When $n$ is negative a reversal of the inequality $\frac{x}{y}<1$ may happen.

Have a look at the Wikipedia page for the [ratio distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim N\left(\mu_{X},\sigma_{X}^{2}\right)$ and $Y\sim N\left(\mu_{Y},\sigma_{Y}^{2}\right)$
and are independent then: $$Z=X-Y\sim N\left(\mu_{X}-\mu_{Y},\sigma_{X}^{2}+\sigma_{Y}^{2}\right)$$
and: $$P\left\{ X<Y\right\} =P\left\{ Z<0\right\} =\cdots $$

---

**edit**:

Let $g\left(x,y\right)$ be prescribed by $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto1$
if $x<y$ and $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto0$ otherwise.

$$P\left\{ X<Y\right\} =\mathbb{E}g\left(X,Y\right)=\int\int g\left(x,y\right)f_{X}\left(x\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y}f_{X}\left(x\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{Y}\left(y\right)\int_{-\infty}^{y}f_{X}\left(x\right)dxdy$$

Comment: I knew for this solution, but what I wanted to ask is how to get the same result by starting as given above.

Comment: Why do you have to take into account only cases where x < y?

Comment: Or to ask more concrete, what is wrong with my idea?

Comment: You are actually saying that $P\left\{ X<Y\right\} =\int F_{X}\left(z\right)\left(1-F_{Y}\left(z\right)\right)dz$.
Based on what? It is simply not true. E.g. choose $F_{X}$ and $F_{Y}$
such that $F_{X}\left(z\right)>\frac{1}{2}$ for $z>0$ and $F_{Y}\left(z\right)<\frac{1}{2}$
for $z<c$ with $c>0$. Then $\int F_{X}\left(z\right)\left(1-F_{Y}\left(z\right)\right)dz\geq\frac{1}{4}c$.
However $c>4$ then gives $\int F_{X}\left(z\right)\left(1-F_{Y}\left(z\right)\right)dz>1$
while at the same time $P\left\{ X<Y\right\} \leq1$. Do you agree with $P\left\{ X<Y\right\} =\mathbb{E}g\left(X,Y\right)$?

Comment: I agree. Well you are absolutely right with your example. But if you take a look in my post, the first equation where I started. I am pretty sure that it is correct, so what can be my next step in order to derive this correctly. I think that I have problem to realize and to visualize what happens when you multiply one function with another and integral that. I don't get the meaning of that and what the outcome represents.

Comment: Your first 'step' is a correct statement. But it is not really applicable when you are looking for $P\{X<Y\}$. In that context it is not really a step into the right direction, hence should just be skipped. A correct route is to start with $P\left\{ X<Y\right\} =\mathbb{E}g\left(X,Y\right)$ and to work out that integral (as I did in my answer).

Comment: So, what I don't understand is what is the "physical" representation of the integral given by drhab? What area is actually that?

Comment: Think $3$- dimensional. The volume between plane $z=0$, function $z=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ and plane $x=y$ on the side where $x<y$ is the mentioned probability.